# Validate the text with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

while typing in an input, I want to validate the text character by character e.g text is: `The Quick Brown Fox`

I want to match character by character

like: initially, text box in empty:

I press

`T`   =>    OK

`h`   =>    OK

`a`   =>    Not Ok (will not be written in the text)

`e`   =>    OK

and so on

I've written this jquery `regex` expression. But, it's not working as it is comparing the whole text.

```
$("#text").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (!(/^The Quick Brown Fox$/i.test($(this).val()+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)))) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are checking for each key press while your regex matches for the entire string. Check once the entire string has been entered.

Comment: You are specifically prepending the entire string (`$(this).val()+`) when you test.

Comment: Why not `lookupString.indexOf($(this).val()) !== -1` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try it like

```
$("#text").on("keypress", function(e) {

    var myText = ($(this).val()+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));

    if ('The Quick Brown Fox'.indexOf(myText) != 0) {
        return false;
    }

});
```

Here is a [**sample fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6NXzs/).

Answer (score 1):

The regex isn't the best choice for doing this kind of thing.

You'll be better off setting up a string and looping through characters, one-by-one until you find a mismatch.

Check the string, from the beginning, each time a key is hit.  That catches people pasting into the `input`.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for each key press while your regex matches for the entire string. Check once the entire string has been entered.

```
$("#text").on("blur", function(e) {
    if (!(/^The Quick Brown Fox$/i.test($(this).val()))) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: But, I want to check while typing.. not after typing.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can loop and compare character by character and do the processing.

**HTML:**
              Enter the Proper text:

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
    var txt = "The Quick Brown Fox";
    var index = 0;
    $("#text").on("keyup", function (e) {
          var st = $('#text').val();
          while (index < st.length) {
              if (txt[index] === st[index]) index++;
              else {
                  $(this).val(st.substr(0, index));
                  break;
              }
          }
    });
```

**LIVE DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/2dadL/21/

Happy Coding :)